# Creating a variable to measure string length

Tags: ruby

So I'm curious as to what I'm missing here. I have a program for school and part of the program requires that I measure the length of the input string. I have it laid out as "if String==6" which you can see in my code below. My professor would rather it be stored in a variable and that I use the .length method to measure it. His exact words are as follows,  "To see if the ticket number is greater than six characters, you need to store it in a variable. Then, on line 19, you can check it by using ticket.length == 6."

I tried using his method and I put "ticket_number.length==6." but that returns an error. Im not sure why, isnt "ticket_number" the variable that needs measured? Or do I need to create another variable just for ticket length? I'm sure there is an easy answer, I just cant seem to find it. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

```
begin 
  print "Please enter your six-digit ticket number."

  ticket_number=gets.chomp.to_i

  ones_digit=ticket_number%10

  truncated_number=ticket_number/10.floor

  remainder=truncated_number%7

  if String=6 and ones_digit==remainder and ticket_number>0

    print "Your ticket number is valid."

  else
    print  "Your ticket number is invalid."
  end
end while ticket_number>0
```

Comment: I thought it measured the length of the string? Or rather, made sure it was =6

Comment: When you entered the input from the beginning, you already have a variable.

Comment: You should post the details of how you are running this program and what input you are giving it, and post the full, exact error message.  Even if it looks like nonsense to you, it will give programmers with more experience a pretty good hint about what is wrong.  See [mcve].

Comment: Colton's comment above referred to a no-longer-there comment from @tadman asking what `String = 6` meant. That causes the constant `String` to now equal `'6'`. It also results in the disappearance of the `String` class, which is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of problems here but the biggest one is that converting to an integer means you've forfeited your opportunity to test vs. length:

```
ticket_number = gets.chomp

if (ticket_number.length != 6)
  puts "Your ticket number must be six digits"

  next
end
```

You can convert after the fact:

```
ticket_number = ticket_number.to_i
```

Then do your math.

Ideally you'd wrap this up in a function that, given a ticket number, will return `true` or `false` depending on validity. This de-couples it from your display and looping logic, simplifying things.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was something simple. I'm just very new to all of this, as in less than three weeks new.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being new. Ruby is particularly forgiving when it comes to those just learning, but don't forget it can't do things it doesn't understand the meaning of. Although the errors can be confusing at first, there's a few patterns to them you'll soon recognize and method missing is the most common. Check `.class` of any object you're interacting with and then you can usually look up the documentation on that class to get a list of valid methods. For example: [Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Integer.html) and [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html).